# file_get_contents doesn't work

Tags: php, file, error-handling

```
$z = file_get_contents("vars.txt");
var_dump($z);
```

This is my current code. When I run it I see this output:

```
string(0) ""
```

I am not sure why - this file contains 321 characters. It is in the same directory with my PHP script. Can you explain me reasons, why that doesn't work? Writing to this file works ok (with "w+" mode).

I though this is `chmod` mistake, but I wrote `chmod 777 dir` command, and still doesn't work.

Full code of my script is there: https://gist.github.com/ty221/274bda4ecec03f710691

Displaying all errors `E_ALL` doesn't work - I mean nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: Is this your entire script?

Comment: Nope... I will pase it

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Nothing has changed

Comment: Full code @Rizier123 https://gist.github.com/ty221/274bda4ecec03f710691

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I will be. GitHub gists are permanent

Comment: You'd like to think that @Ty221, but no external source can be guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

And a quote from there:

> 'w+'   Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^

That means with your line:

```
//Deletes all content in the file
$file = fopen("vars.txt", "w+");

$to_save = "";

//Reads the content from a empty file
$z = file_get_contents("vars.txt");
//Outputs an empty string
var_dump($z);
```

Comment: nice catch.That's why op need to write full code when asking question

Comment: wow you really have good eye